# Where is "Back Home" in Casino?

Tags: plot-explanation, casino

In the movie *Casino* (1995) both Sam and Nicky move to Las Vegas from "Back Home" where the bosses are. It is clear that they both started their career in in their "home" town.

**Which city do they refer to when they say "Back Home"?**

I believe it is either New York or Chicago.

At some point Nicky mentions that the bosses are 1500 miles away. Chicago is 1700 miles, so it might be Chicago. I only found that piece of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back Home is a reference to Chicago, From [mentalfloss](http://mentalfloss.com/article/68258/12-high-stakes-facts-about-casino)

> You're always in dangerous waters making a movie about the mafia, even when most of the facts are a matter of public record. According to Scorsese, Universal's lawyers suggested changing the characters' names (hence Frank "Lefty" Rosenthal becomes Sam "Ace" Rothstein), and even **avoiding specific mention of Chicago being the Las Vegas mobsters' headquarters**: they say "back home" instead, and the word "Chicago" never appears in the screenplay.

Also mentioned in [vitalvegas](https://vitalvegas.com/weird-wonderful-useless-facts-casino-movie/) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casino_(1995_film)#Development).

Comment: This isn't completely right.  Yes, it's Chicago, but they do explicitly say Chicago in the movie.

Comment: @JohnnyBones in negative context?

Comment: I think in reference to the "Chicago Outfit".  But, as I recall, the "back home" in the movie was actually Kansas City, though clearly they were talking about Chicago.

Comment: @JohnnyBones from article it seems they removed mention of Chicago as mobsters' headquarters. So maybe rest they didn't cared

Comment: I'd have to re-watch it, but I remember it was made clear they were in Kansas City and the operation was run by the Chicago Outfit.  Next time I watch it I can get more specific info and post it here.

Comment: @JohnnyBones ok sure :)

Comment: Kansas City is about 1350 miles from Las Vegas, if that makes a difference